# Which has faster lookups, Berkeley DB or indexed PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, berkeley-db

I am currently using a database with the following use constraints:

- optimized for fast, single row lookups (key-value pairs are fine)
- millions of rows (probably <10M though)
- no need for relational joins etc.
- potential for multi-user and multi-threaded access

It was originally developed using PostgreSQL because we had familiarity with that type of db. Now it's too slow to be useful for doing lookups and updates (it's a cache so speed is everything). We are currently testing different ways to index the PostgreSQL table for faster lookup, but I would like to know from someone with experience whether a Berkeley DB would be even faster than an optimally keyed PostgreSQl db?

Comment: Lookups aren't your only issue if you're doing many updates, which, using this as a caching system, you're doing. Those updates could regularly mess with table layouts if you don't have enough padding in your pages to handle the various sizes of data effectively. (How much? I can't say.)  Also, Ideally, for lookups, you want your common data requests to process with as few page fetches as possible in as few transactions as reasonable.  If your data retrieval isn't attempting that, there's no point in switching databases until you have managed your data retrieval strategies better.

Comment: Have you properly tuned your Postgresql db? Is autovacuum aggressive enough? What version of Postgresql are you using? What is slow, the updates or the SELECTs? Is table and index bloat playing a part of that? What about indexings, perhaps you have inappropriate indexes? There are many more questions that can be asked to try to speed up your existing database, before committing to a cut-over to a different one. If you are determined to move away from Postgres, have you considered a database like Redis or Memcached?

Comment: You seem to have left out your `explain analyze` results, PostgreSQL version, settings, and other key details. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql/info . Also, did you benchmark and compare yourself, with a simulation of *your* workload? Different DB engines are faster for different things.

Comment: These comments are all very telling: it does not sound like Berkeley DB should be head-and-shoulders faster than a well tuned/indexed PostgreSQL DB given this size and these constraints. I need to invest in more time benchmarking and tuning before I can answer all your questions. Thanks and I will be back.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that you're not indexing it as well as it could be? (10M rows is tiny... Postgres can and does handle terabytes of data.)

That said, if it's *just* a cache, have you considered creating a RAM drive and a tablespace for it?

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/manage-ag-tablespaces.html

You can make tables within it unlogged as well to speed things up further (it's not as if this matters much, if it's really just a cache): you'll end up with something similar to memcached, with the benefit of postgresql syntax and datatypes.